# minFunc package usage

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, gradient-descent

I have been using MATLAB fminunc function to solve my optimization problem. I want to try the minFunc package :

http://www.di.ens.fr/~mschmidt/Software/minFunc.html

When using fminunc, I defined a function funObj.m which gives me the objective value and the gradient at any point 'x'. It also takes in several external inputs say, {a,b,c} which are matrices. So the function prototype looks like :

```
function [objVal,G] = funObj(x,a,b,c)
```

I want to use the same setup in the minFunc package. From the examples, I figured this should work :

```
options.Method='lbfgs';
f = @(x)funObj(x,a,b,c);
x = minFunc(f,x_init,options);
```

But when I call this way, I get an error as:

```
Error using funObj
Too many output arguments.
```

What is the correct way to call minFunc for my case?

****EDIT : Alright, here is a sample function that I want to use with minFunc. Lets say I want to find the minimum of a*(b-x)^2, where a,b are scalar parameters and x being a scalar too. The MATLAB objective function will then look like :

```
function obj = testFunc(x,a,b)
obj = a*(b-x)^2;
```

The function call to minimize this using fminunc (in MATLAB ) is simply:

```
f = @(x)testFunc(x,a,b);
x = fminunc(f,x_init);
```

This gives me the minimum of x = 10. Now, How do I do the same using minFunc ?

Comment: Does it work on the included [Rosenbrock](http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/~edward/code/minimize/rosenbrock.m) function?

Comment: Yes, the same call works for rosenbrock function. But the rosenbrock function does not include any extra parameters, so it works fine.

Comment: Would it possible for you to include a Minimal Working Example of your function?

Answer (score 4):

"Note that by default minFunc assumes that the gradient is supplied, unless the 'numDiff' option is set to 1 (for forward-differencing) or 2 (for central-differencing)."

The error is because only one argument is returned by the function. You can either return the gradient as a second argument or turn on numerical differencing.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I knew the problem was something like this, but I could not find the name of the variable to toggle ( options.numDiff as you mentioned here ). Now, it is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Mark. I think the simplest way to solve it is

```
minFunc(@testFunc, x_init, a, b, c)
```

In MATLAB temporary function can only have one return value. So `f = @(x)testFunc(x,a,b);` let your method drop gradient part every time. Because `minFunc` can accept extra paramters, you can pass `a`, `b` and `c` after `x_init`. I think this would work.

Comment: This was a while ago, but I had the same issue. You can use 'deal' to return multiple values, so

obj = @(x) deal( f(x), gradf(x) ) 

should work.